# GWT : Keep minimum size for SplitLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, size, panel, uibinder, minimum

I'm working on a GWT project and I'm using the SplitLayoutPanel. My page is divided in several panels that I can resize. My problem comes from the fact I can't specify a minimum height for my panels.

By example, if my panel is 300px height, user can enlarge it until 500px but not more and can not reduce it under 300px.

I'm using the uibinder.

Edit : I'd like to do this kind of thing : http://www.ann0yanc3.com/Ext.layout.HBoxFitSplit/

Here's a link where the code's given : http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-65982.html

If somebody has an easier solution, he's the welcome !

Thanks

Seb

Comment: it's definitly implemented in the split layout panel, so you probably have to do some coding on your own. If you find a widget which implements this functionallity and works similar to the spilt layout panel, please post it!

Answer (score 0):

On the SplitLayoutPanel, there is this method :

```
  public void setWidgetMinSize(Widget child, int minSize)
```

In you view, you can use @UiField to have access to your SplitLayoutPanel and childs, then you can call the method above.